# VBA: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this to move orders from the new orders page to the previous orders page however I get the title error when I attempt to run it. I have looked at several different places to try to get it to work and I see that theirs should work but mine isn't.

```
Sheets("New_Orders").Range("B3:E29").Cut

Sheets("Previous_Orders").Range("B31").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This is more code that is supposed to do the same thing that isn't working either

```
Sheets("New_Orders").Select
Range("B3:E29").Select
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Previous_Orders").Select
Range("B:B").Find("").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I have tried Selection.Copy as well. It gave the same error

Comment: You can only paste all or insert with cut.

Comment: [Must. Read.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Comment: Must watch: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This is the relevant video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5&t=3072s)

Answer (score 3):

As stated above in the comment you can only Paste everything when using Cut.  If only values are wanted then assign the values directly then clear the range.

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set rng = Sheets("New_Orders").Range("B3:E29")
With Sheets("Previous_Orders")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(lastRow, 2).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
End With
rng.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain the comment edited into the question, i.e. `I have tried Selection.Copy as well. It gave the same error`  (But I can't get `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial` to work anyway - I would have thought that it would need to be `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial` - so I'm not too sure how accurate the "same error" comment is.)

Comment: Was just typing the same when I saw your edit @YowE3K  It should work with ActiveCell and Copy.

Comment: When I run it it gives me Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: @CollinStacey on which line?

Comment: @CollinStacey never mind I found the error see the edit.